# logcat error Index -1 requested, with a size of 24

Tags: android, database, android-logcat

I got this error when running a project that uses the SqliteAssetHelper library:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 24
at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Cursor` is not positioned on a valid row. Use `moveToFirst()` or one of the other `move...()` methods to position the `Cursor` on the row that you wish to read from.